# Clone a google compute engine instance to a local Server

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a `vm` instance on google compute engine, which deploys a python web application. But now i want to have a snapshot of the online `vm` deplyed on my local server. Is it feasible to do that? if yes, how do i proceed to do that?

Comment: The steps to export a GCE instance to Google Cloud Storage are documented on this link (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image#export_an_image_to_google_cloud_storage). You can go through the steps to see if that image works on your local machine using a visualization software (e.g. virtualbox etc).